# Reloading view page each 2 seconds without refresh page on MVC4

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I've a page in MVC which I want to reload automatically every 2 seconds without doing a refresh, I have seen examples
with Ajax but all referenced using buttons or in POST-GET events. I only want it to reload without refresh,
What can I do to perform that function?
Thank you

This's my view

```
@model MVC_PCMonitoring_Dash.Models.TablesPCModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        
        <div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="custom-menu">

        </div>
            <div class="img bg-wrap text-center py-4" style="background-color: #A40033;">
                <div class="user-logo">
                      <div class="img" style="background-image: url(Images/logo.jpg)"></div>
                    <h3>TOTAL PC</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
          <li class="active">
            <a href="/Home"> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="/Monitor_BA"> PC 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/Monitor_BB"> PC 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Exit</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
      <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">
          <p align="right">@DateTime.Now</p>
          <center>
            <img src="~/Images/welcome.png" alt="centered image" />
          </center>
      </div>
      </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use timer and ajax in this case.

```
setInterval(function(){ --ajax call to refresh---},2000)  //2000 means 2 min
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it reloads but I need it not to refresh.

Comment: Okay it got it. Sorry my bad I took it wrong. <br/>

Comment: But your answer complement a function that i found, $( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" );

Comment: So, I just accept your answer @Vikas Bhukar Thanks!